# Convert character to datetime object produces NAs

Tags: r, datetime

I have this character vector but when I try to convert it to datetime object I get `NAs`

```
timess<-c("11.01.2021 04:40", "03.01.2021 05:45", "30.12.2020 02:28", 
"02.01.2021 08:13", "03.01.2021 05:45", "04.01.2021 04:33", "03.01.2021 05:45", 
"02.01.2021 08:13", "03.01.2021 05:45", "02.01.2021 08:13")

timess<-as.POSIXct(timess, format="%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Or, `as.POSIXct(timess, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
[1] "2021-01-11 04:40:00 EST"`, again as to format string, since %S is not in the input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` the seconds to the strings, and take good care of the format string, see`?strptime`.

```
as.POSIXct(paste0(timess, ':00'), format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
# [1] "2021-01-11 04:40:00 CET" "2021-01-03 05:45:00 CET"
# [3] "2020-12-30 02:28:00 CET" "2021-01-02 08:13:00 CET"
# [5] "2021-01-03 05:45:00 CET" "2021-01-04 04:33:00 CET"
# [7] "2021-01-03 05:45:00 CET" "2021-01-02 08:13:00 CET"
# [9] "2021-01-03 05:45:00 CET" "2021-01-02 08:13:00 CET"
```